# Applying for a PhD with professor X, when my prior research is in a different field?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science

In an ideal scenario, I’d like to do my (computer science) PhD at university U. I completely lack the credentials, and my MS work is in one of those areas where ~10 people in the world are capable of understanding/appreciating it (and it won’t be published anytime soon). Fortunately, one of those people is Professor X (they contacted me unexpectedly saying that they liked my work, having evidently seen my code-in-progress). Great, right?

Unfortunately, I don’t want to work with Professor X, I want to work with Professor Y, because I want to switch to a completely different field of CS. I have nothing against X or our field, I’ve just gotten really interested in Y’s field, and Y is arguably the best person in the world study under for these interests. So while I feel quite confident that I do want to make this switch, the fact is that currently I don’t have anything to “show” Y (in terms of credentials or research in their field).

Do I have any good angle here?

Comment: But how exactly? The only research I have is my thesis, which is in a topic arcane enough that it seems ~10 people in the world understand it.

Comment: Wait, how do you 'completely lack the credentials', yet are getting/have gotten a masters in the field? Talk to Y, apply to get in, see what happens. Nobody works on the same problem forever...

Comment: The question you should be asking is "How can I build some credentials in Y's field". Without such credentials, it seems unlikely that Y would be interested in hiring you.

Comment: This is a bit orthogonal, but my dissertation was (worldwide) accessible to about half a dozen people. But it resulted in a TransAMS publication. But I didn't have the conflict you do, since I loved that work.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have any good angle here?

That depends on what you want to achieve and how long you’re willing to take to achieve it.

> Fortunately, one of those people is Professor X (they contacted me unexpectedly saying that they liked my work, having evidently seen my code-in-progress). Great, right?

Is taking a short-term appointment with X an option? That will offer you a chance to work on your problem and get a reference from a world expert.

Comment: Well, if they agree ahead of time it’s a 6month/1 year visit then why would anyone be upset or surprised?

Comment: Can CS grad students do fixed, short-term appointments? I haven't  heard of this being a thing, although I did consider asking X about this (candidly of course). I'm not completely enthusiastic about this since it would mean working more in a topic I'm less interested in when I already feel like moving on to something that excites me more now, but I suppose beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: I had five of them over the years. They are often called research assistants or something of the sort. Not all professors have funding or inclination to do it, but it’s worth asking.